# Image and audio lossless file format

Tags: video, audio, compression, file-format, photo

I know that JPG and MP3 always apply some kind of compression which losses data. Then I have to questions:
- Which are the lossless file formats for image, audio and video?
- Why, as far as I know, any photocamera does not offer the possibility to store images in a lossless file format?
- I know that the data lost is really small but, what can I do if HQ is extremely important? Can I take a picture in a lossless way?

THANKS

Comment: RAW is used in digital cameras to designate formats where no additional information is lost (with respect to the information that has already been lost by the sensor). Similarly, a plain WAV file can represent the samples of a sound with no additional loss of information after the sampling (beware, WAV is a meta-format and can designate several representations for sounds).

Answer (score 1):

**Audio**: please consider FLAC ([Free Lossless Audio Codec](http://flac.sourceforge.net/))

**Image**: please consider [JPEG2000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_2000) that supports lossless encoding too.

I just came back from [IBC Amsterdam](http://www.ibc.org/), and I met some guys specialized in [JPEG2000 lossless video compression](http://www.intopix.com/products/index/index/id/3/lang/en). Impressive.

Answer (score 0):

For audio .WAV is lossless format.In images .PNG is a lossless format.

Answer (score 0):

For lossless compression of audio, [FLAC](http://flac.sourceforge.net/) is the encoder of choice.

Video, especially HD video is extremely data intensive with lossless data rates in excess of 40Mb/s. Outside of tape, it is pretty hard to sustain those data rates so mostly all digital video entails some compression scheme of which [H.264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) is becoming a dominant standard.

Answer (score 0):

As previous answers have noted, FLAC is the most widespread format for lossless audio compression. WAV is lossless but uncompressed.